# How enable application-wide color schemes?

Tags: delphi, background-color, color-scheme

I would like to apply color schemes to my application. This is done by making all components have their `ParentColor` set to `true` as well as `ParentBackground` and `ParentFont`. When I change the form color everything changes. There is an exception: toolbars and toolbuttons don't change. Is it possible to change them with the color of the form or must I implement this in a separate way?

The same applies to font colors, but that is a trifle more strange. When I change the font color of the form the font color of a groupbox caption does not change but the caption of label captions (also inside the groupbox) change allright.

When implementing some way to allow the user choose his own colors is this the way to go (change the form color, make all components have `ParentColor` set) or are there better ways to achieve this goal?

Comment: Many of the Windows controls are not designed to support arbitrary colors. The latest version of Delphi, XE2, introduces a new feature called VCL styles. This is probably the easiest and quickest way to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: And some of them, like group boxes, check or radio buttons might be affected by themes, so you can't specify font nor parent font to them. You would have to modify them for this support. Or you may get Delphi XE2 where, as David pointed are VCL styles.

Comment: This means to keep enumerate the components you want to change and assign them the color you would like. I hoped I'd forgotten something :-) I don't have XE2 yet, but this VCL scheme sounds interesting. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Arnold; Your question could also be asked simply as "How do I skin, or theme, my applications" and as such, is kind of a duplicate. There are many old techniques with versions prior to XE2, but the simplest answer is to follow David's advice and go with XE2 and the new "VCL themes" support in it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Theme-ing applications in Delphi XE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077473/theme-ing-applications-in-delphi-xe)

Comment: @Warren, Thanks for this link, it's a useful one.

Answer (score 1):

One way to acheive this is to use `interfaces`.

It is a bit of (manual) work, but if you'd like to do it in a simple manner you could simply define an interface and ensure all your forms implement this interface.

for example:

```
type ITheme = interface
  procedure SetTheme(const AColor : TColor);
end;
```

then in each of you forms you could implement this interface.

So to change all of your forms' colors you simply need to call 1 function:

```
procedure SetGlobalTheme(const AColor : TColor);
var Intf : ITheme;
begin
  for i:=0 to screen.Formcount-1 do
  begin
    if Supports(Screen.Forms[i],ITheme,intf) then
      intf.SetTheme(AColor);
  end;
end;
```

Using this method you have full control of each components color, albeit with some more coding to be done. The alternative is to use David suggestion of VCL styles (if your IDE supports it)

Comment: This is a useful tip if I'd many forms but I have only one and by this question I hoped to learn how to avoid implementing the colors manually which I do now.